# Non aggregate multiple pivot - Got stuck MS SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I've almost completed my MS SQL query using multiple pivot non aggregate function, can't able to produce the desired result.
can anyone help me out, not sure what I'm missing?
And also if there is a simpler solution please feel free to share.

Any help will be much appreciated!

**SQL Fiddle**

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0103d/1/0

[image: Pivot query Issue]

Comment: The SQL Fiddle is nice.  Even so, the query should go in the question.

Comment: The sample is great but too many unnecesary colums. If you keep it simple producing the same result will be easier to understand. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is hardcoded **PIVOT** with maximum 10 columns. I remake your query to in my opinion more readable form.

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376772)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY policyID ORDER BY policyID)
  FROM #tbl_policy_client_details
)
SELECT policyID
  ,[No of travellers]    = COUNT(*)
  ,[Traveller 1 - Age]  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 1]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 1]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 1]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)

  ,[Traveller 2 - Age]  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 2]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 2]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 2]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)

  ,[Traveller 3 - Age]  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 3]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 3]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 3]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)

  ,[Traveller 4 - Age]  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 4]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 4]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 4]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)

  ,[Traveller 5 - Age]  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 5]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 5]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 5]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)

  ,[Traveller6 - Age]   = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 6]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 6]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 6]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)

  ,[Traveller 7 - Age]  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 7 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 7]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 7 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 7]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 7 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 7]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 7 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)

  ,[Traveller 8 - Age]  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 8 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 8]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 8 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 8]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 8 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 8]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 8 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)

  ,[Traveller 9 - Age]  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 9 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 9]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 9 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 9]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 9 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 9]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 9 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)

  ,[Traveller 10 - Age]  = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 10 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 10]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 10 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 10]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 10 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 10]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 10 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)
FROM cte
GROUP BY policyID
```

How it works:

It is very simple `GROUP BY` with multiplied columns to hold up to 10 customers per group. Just like your `PIVOT`.

```
SELECT policyID
  ,[No of travellers]    = COUNT(*)
  ,[Traveller 1 - Age]   = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Age END)
  ,[Name 1]              = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN FirstName END)
  ,[Surname 1]           = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Surname END)
  ,[Type Condition 1]    = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN IIF(TypeID IS NULL , 'No', 'Yes') END)
FROM cte
GROUP BY policyID;
```

**EDIT:**

The reason your initial query is not working is because you use string literal and not name columns. Use instead:

```
With client_details AS
(
SELECT cd.*,
  CASE WHEN TypeID IS NULL THEN 'No' Else 'Yes' END [TypeResult]
  ,'Age'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY cd.PolicyID ORDER BY TravellerID DESC)) AS [Ages] 
  ,'name'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY cd.PolicyID ORDER BY TravellerID DESC))AS [Name] 
  ,'surname'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY cd.PolicyID ORDER BY TravellerID DESC)) AS [Surnames],
  'Type'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY cd.PolicyID ORDER BY TravellerID DESC)) AS [Type] 
FROM tbl_policy_client_details cd
WHERE cd.PolicyID IS not NULL)
SELECT 
  policyID
  ,COUNT(PolicyID)[No of travellers]
  ,MAX(Age1) [Traveller 1 - Age],MAX(Name1) [Name 1],MAX(Surname1) [Surname 1],MAX(Type1) [Type Condition 1]
  ,MAX(Age2) [Traveller 2 - Age],MAX(Name2) [Name 2],MAX(Surname1) [Surname 2],MAX(Type2) [Type Condition 2]
  ,MAX(Age3) [Traveller 3 - Age],MAX(Name3) [Name 3],MAX(Surname1) [Surname 3],MAX(Type3) [Type Condition 3]
  ,MAX(Age4) [Traveller 4 - Age],MAX(Name4) [Name 4],MAX(Surname1) [Surname 4],MAX(Type4) [Type Condition 4]
  ,MAX(Age5) [Traveller 5 - Age],MAX(Name5) [Name 5],MAX(Surname1) [Surname 5],MAX(Type5) [Type Condition 5]
  -- ...
FROM
(SELECT cd.*
FROM client_details cd) p
PIVOT(MAX(Age)FOR Ages IN ([Age1],[Age2],[Age3],[Age4],[Age5],[Age6],[Age7],[Age8],[Age9],[Age10])) AS pvt
PIVOT (MAX(Firstname)
FOR Name IN ([Name1],[Name2],[Name3],[Name4],[Name5],[Name6],[Name7],[Name8],[Name9],[Name10])) AS Pivot1
PIVOT (MAX(Surnames)
FOR Surname IN ([Surname1],[Surname2],[Surname3],[Surname4],[Surname5],[Surname6],[Surname7],[Surname8],[Surname9],[Surname10])) AS Pivot2
PIVOT (MAX(TypeResult)
FOR Type IN ([Type1],[Type2],[Type3],[Type4],[Type5],[Type6],[Type7],[Type8],[Type9],[Type10])) AS Pivot3
GROUP BY Pivot3.policyID;
```

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0103d/21/0)**

Comment: Thanks lad2025, just of curiosity whats wrong in the pivot ?

Comment: you are awesome, thanks for the explanation too. Wish I could up-vote by +100 :)

Comment: @Binny Happy to hear it. You can read my other answers, I hope you will learn a lot :)